# Maven 3 and Cargo - 'No plugin found for prefix 'cargo''

Tags: tomcat, maven-3, maven-cargo

I have just added the following code to my pom.xml (as specified on [here](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin)) :

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <zipUrlInstaller>
                        <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.12/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.12.zip</url>
                    </zipUrlInstaller>
                </container>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

However, when I run `mvn clean verify cargo:run` I am getting the following :

```
No plugin found for prefix 'cargo' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why didn't you configure the cargo-maven2-plugin to run in the pre-integration test phase instead of calling it via command line manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to define the [pluginGroup](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Plugin_Groups) to be able to use the abbreviation on command line.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is specify full plugin name `org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin` instead `cargo`.

For you will be `mvn clean verify org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:run`

Answer (score 0):

This is my configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                </container>
                <deployables>
                    <deployable>
                        <type>war</type>
                        <location>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</location>
                        <properties>
                            <context>/</context>
                        </properties>
                    </deployable>
                </deployables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

cargo-maven2-plugin has been replaced by cargo-maven3-plugin. See my working config here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76372717/1384839